# Separate string into three pieces using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string: "User john.hughes logged in from 192.168.82.245"

How to separate it into two pieces with regular expressions: "User logged in from 192.168.82.245", "john.hughes" ?

I have tried this (im using perl):

```
$message =~ /(\w+) (.+) (.+)/;
my($user,$msg) = ($2,"$1 $3");
```

But it doesn't work and $user equals "aleksandr.fetisov logged in from", instead of "aleksandr.fetisov"

A problem is that my string can also be equal "User john.hughes logged in"
and in that case user and msg must be equal "User logged in", "john.hughes"

Comment: Use `/^(\w+) (\S+) (.+)/`

Comment: You are trying to be very dynamic. Is it always the same pattern? Is there always an IPv4 address? Does it always say "User <name> logged in"?

Answer (score -1):

Your two types of string seem to have a fixed component in the front, and your usernames cannot have spaces. You can use these two things to craft a pattern and use substitution.

```
my $str = "User john.hughes logged in from 127.0.0.1";
$str =~ s/(?<=User\s)(\S+)\s//;
print "$1, $str";
```

This uses a more advanced regex feature called a [*positive lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Essentially there needs to be the pattern `User` (with a space, which I've represented by a `\s` whitespace as that is easier to read than random whitespace in your pattern) before anything is matched. The username has no whitespace, so we can capture as many whitespace characters as possible `\S+` afterwards. And that's followed by a space.

Then we replace this with nothing. The good thing about the lookbehind is that it's not part of the pattern that will be substituted. So the result of the substitution will be that the username and it's directly following whitespace character are gone from the string. Because there's one capture group `()`, the username will go into `$1`.